# ember-cli mocks doesn't return single record

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I'm building a simple ember-cli app. And I tried to implement new mocks feature.

**server/mocks/users.js**

```
module.exports = function (app) {
  var express = require('express');
  var usersRouter = express.Router();
  usersRouter.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.send({"users": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "login": 'berdof'
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "login": 'berdof2'
      }
    ]});
  });
  app.use('/api/users', usersRouter);
};
```

Next when I'm trying to fetch the data, for instance in browser, I just open

`http://0.0.0.0:4200/api/user/`

and get the correct data. But when I want to fetch a single record it just throws me an error

```
Cannot GET /api/users/1
```

Do you know why's that? I've been fighting with this bug for about 2 hours. 
Thanks you for any help! Have a good day!

**Update**

Here's the modified answer according to @kaungst post:

```
module.exports = function (app) {
  var express = require('express');
  var router = express.Router();
  var dataToSend = [
    {
      id: 1,
      login: 'berdof',
    },
    {
      id: 1,
      login: 'berdof2'
    }
  ];

  router.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.send({"users": dataToSend});
  });
  router.get('/:id', function (req, res) {
    var id = req.params.id;
    res.send({"user": dataToSend[id]});
  });
  app.use('/api/users', router);
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to create an additional mock to handle that case

for this specific example run

```
ember g http-mock user
```

which should generate the following in <\app-name>/server/mocks/user.js

```
module.exports = function (app) {
    var express = require('express');
    var userRouter = express.Router();
    userRouter.get('/', function (req, res) {
        res.send({"user": []});
    });
    app.use('/api/user', userRouter);
};
```

alter it to look like this

```
module.exports = function (app) {
    var express = require('express');
    var userRouter = express.Router();
    userRouter.get('/', function (req, res) {
        // this part is hacky but works
        // main thing is to decide what you want to send
        // happy to update if someone knows a better solution
        var url = req.baseUrl.split('/');
        var id = parseInt(url[url.length-1]);
        var users = [{
            "id": 1,
            "login": 'berdof'
            },
            {
            "id": 2,
            "login": 'berdof2'
        }];

        res.send({"user": users[id]});
    });
    app.use('/api/user/:id', userRouter);
};
```

Comment: Thanks! Nice solution! I was thinking about something similar but thought there could be this done in ember-cli. I tweaked your code so it now can return both single record and plurals. If you have thoughts about improving my code I would like to hear it!

Comment: How do you handle the problem, that you, f.e. want to fetch the first json object in your model and would intuitively set `1` as the required parameter in your route, but in the http-mock send command `res.send({"user": users[id]});` you will automatically not fetch the first, but the second object, since `users` is created as an array and `users[1]` will return the object with the id 2 (at least with the implementation of @AlexBerdyshev above). I now solved it with `var id = req.params.id -1;` in my use case, but it is somewhat hacky. Is there a more "ember" way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

**Better alternative to http-mocks**

I would recommend using [ember-cli-mirage](http://www.ember-cli-mirage.com/) for client-side development and testing.
The project website provides enough detailed documentation

**Benefits**

- It creates an in-memory db which supports all the CRUD operations.
- Use the same data for both development and testing.
- Integrates well with [faker.js](https://github.com/Marak/faker.js) to create random data.
- Ability to create fixtures.

Having struggled with using http-mocks, I would highly recommend it.